# Huggingface BertForMaskedLM fails after 90+ iterations

Tags: jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, apple-m1

I'm using BertForMaskedLM in Jupyter Notebooks. `output = model(masked_arr)` wouldn't run after 89-95 iterations. Each time I try running the cell it would fail after a different number of iterations in that range. (I tested this by making print statements before the line as well as a count of the iteration.) I'm on M1 Macbook Air 2020. I'm wondering if this is an issue with BertForMaskedLM/I'm using it the wrong way/hardware issue. The cell would show still running and not show any error.

```
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

imp = {}
for count, id_to_mask in enumerate(unique_ids):
    # mask all occurences of word
    masked_arr = torch.tensor([[103 if x==id_to_mask else x for x in input_ids]])
    # pass masked document into BertForMaskedLM
    output = model(masked_arr)
    # find indices of word in document
    idxs = np.where(input_ids==id_to_mask)[0]
    # find probability of word from bert output
    prob = output.logits[0][idxs][:,id_to_mask]
    # summation for all occurencesof word
    sum_prob = prob.sum()
    # debug
    print(count)
    # store in dict
    imp[id_to_mask] = sum_prob
```

Comment: Can you check if it is always the same input that causes your code to hang? Is anything printed when you execute it from the terminal?

Comment: @cronoik yes its the same input. for example, on one iteration it might hang on the 98th iteration for id 5302 and on another run it would get past that but hang on the 99th iteration for id 2240. nothing is printed. and the cell still shows as running.

Comment: What I wanted to know, is if it always hangs for id 2240 and 5302? :)

Comment: @cronoik no. everytime its different. there are times those ids work

Comment: Maybe you should open a bug report on github.

Comment: Adding to @cronoik, can you check if the inputs are not empty??